# What are Window's FFT functions?

Tags: c++, winapi, fft

I'm writing a Win32 application, using just C++ and WinApi calls. I need to run an 8192-point FFT over 20ms of WAVEFORMATEX data. What would be the most efficient method of accomplishing this?

Comment: I think you meant 8192-point FFT.

Comment: You are correct, edited.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415925(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: todda is correct. Interestingly, that page does not show up for some time when you Google 'msdn fft'. Only FFPolar appears. I apologize, it seems like I should have been able to easily find this with Google.

Comment: It shows up when you search for `msdn fourier transform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we fleshed out in the comments, the MSDN Documentation for [XDSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415925(v=vs.85).aspx) functions may be of relevance to you.

The functions don't appear to take `WAVEFORMATEX` directly, but if you can convert it to the appropriate format you can use [`FFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.xdsp.fft(v=vs.85).aspx) to do what you want.

Note that it's part of the DirectX SDK, so you're introducing a new dependency.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time, but I recall this code library as being very fast and easy to compile:

http://fftw.org/

Comment: Licensing may be a problem though

Comment: Ugghh... I missed the GNU stamp. Seems like they do offer a pay-for license, but my guess is that it will be and arm and a leg.  Doesn't hurt to ring them up and ask. http://fftw.org/faq/section1.html#nonfree

Comment: Last time I checked it was $5,000 for a commercial license.

Answer (score 2):

[KISSFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) is not a windows api, per se. However it is small enough to embed nicely in any project -- about 30kb of ANSI C sourcecode for the basic complex-to-complex transform.
Unlike other super-tiny FFT libraries, it is fast, featureful, accurate, and can be used in a multi-threaded program.

One of the key features is that KISSFFT can do mixed radix (multiples of 2,3,5 are fastest).  Other "bolt-on" features are available in the tools directory.  Use only the pieces you need for: multi-dimensional transforms, real-optimized transforms (i.e. half spectrum), fast convolution, etc

The [speed](http://www.fftw.org/speed/CoreDuo-3.0GHz-icc64/) is generally fast enough for most applications -- not quite as fast as fftw or vendor libraries, but faster than the builk of the remainder.

KISSFFT's [accuracy](http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/CoreDuo-3.0GHz-icc64/) is as good as any FFT library out there.

The license is [3 clause BSD](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ModifiedBSD) which can legally be used inside a commercial app at one end of the spectrum or a GPL app at the other end. It just requires a simple attribution in the docs.